# In apt, How to move package from direct package to transitive package?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I'm looking for a command that:

- remove/purge a package if it is not a transitive package of another install package
- declare a directly installed package as installed-by-transitivity if it is a transitive package of another install package

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apt-mark` to set a package to `automatically installed`.

Example:

```
$ sudo apt install php8.1-cli
$ apt search php8.1-cli
php8.1-cli/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14 amd64 [installed]
$ sudo apt install php
$ apt search php8.1-cli
php8.1-cli/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14 amd64 [installed]
$ sudo apt-mark auto php8.1-cli
php8.1-cli set to automatically installed.
$ apt search php8.1-cli
php8.1-cli/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14 amd64 [installed,automatic]
$ sudo apt remove php
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils bzip2 file libapache2-mod-php8.1 libapr1
  libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap libargon2-1 libbrotli1 libbsd0 libcurl4
  libedit2 libexpat1 libgdbm-compat4 libgdbm6 libicu70 libjansson4 libldap-2.5-0 libldap-common
  liblua5.3-0 libmagic-mgc libmagic1 libmd0 libnghttp2-14 libperl5.34 libpsl5 librtmp1
  libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db libsodium23 libsqlite3-0 libssh-4 libxml2
  mailcap media-types mime-support netbase perl perl-modules-5.34 php-common php8.1 php8.1-cli
  php8.1-common php8.1-opcache php8.1-readline publicsuffix ssl-cert tzdata ucf xz-utils
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
```

I first installed `php8.1-cli`, which is a dependency of the `php` package. It is shown as `[installed]`. After running `apt-mark auto php8.1-cli` it is marked as `[installed,automatic]`. When I now uninstall the `php` package it is listed as `automatically installed` and will be removed with `apt autoremove`, along with all other packages.